# Firebase Function trigged when date/time value expired

Tags: flutter

İs it possible Firebase Function trigged when Firestore date/time field value < Current Date/Time (mean expired) and send notification?

If not possible, is there another way?

Do you know about this?
ThankS your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shall try cloud function and schedule it for everyday at a certain time just like we check for unused accounts and delete them.

Refer for such function:-[Link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron/functions/index.js)